# Alternatives to white listing multiple external ip in restricted network

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, security

I have a use case where at a customer site I have to instruct the customer to white list numerous external server ip addresses.  Users in the company have to be able to connect to each individual server.  This is cumbersome for their IT department.  I'm trying to formulate a solution where they could just white list one ip address or a domain name.

One solution is to use a reverse proxy that the users would connect to, but there will be ports other than 80 and 443 that users connect to.  I could use that along with a jump box for ssh, but I don't really like this approach, and there will be other obscure ports that they'll need to connect to.

Second option is to use a vpn that the customer could connect to.  Then they could just connect to the servers inside my vpc (AWS).

Third option is to give each server a dns name like server1.example.com, server2.example.com, etc.  Then the customer could just whitelist example.com.  I'm not sure though how the customer's dns setup would play with this though.

Has anyone else ever tackled a problem like this?  I'm trying to figure out the easiest solution.

Y

Comment: `I have a use case where at a customer site I have to instruct the customer to white list numerous external server ip addresses.` - Whitelist them where? In the customer firewall? Whitelist them for what traffic? HTTP/HTTPS? You need to provide specific details.

Comment: Yes, the customer has to whitelist the ip addresses on their firewall for internal employees to be able to access them.  There are various ports on the external servers that they'd need to hit.  Not just 80 and 443.  The idea is to not have to ask them to whitelist 40 different ip addresses.

Comment: Your customer has taken this pain upon themselves intentionally. Give them 40 IP addresses. Or 400. If they really didn't want to suffer this, they'd be offering you a VPN connection. But don't make the world worse by introducing more needless NAT and jumpboxes if you can avoid it.

Comment: The issue is that I am providing training to the customer.  Some customers like financial institutions have really strict security policies.  I'm trying to create a good experience for them regardless of their network setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your customer is a bit serious about security, you will not be allowed to create a VPN from/to their network. If they allow you to create a VPN, they will put it behind a firewall, and they still have to put in your 40 addresses (or 400). In general, white-listing a DNS name is done only in proxies; real firewalls do not trust DNS.

So, either go for the proxy/jumphost if you are comfortable with that or give them the 400 IP addresses. I do not think they will be surprised.

You might also give them a subnet. If you organize your servers in such a way that you could give them a /25 or /26 and you guarantee that their are only his servers in that subnet, that may be easier.

Comment: Out of curiosity how would that work if a Firewall doesn't trust dns?  How would websites be white listed in a firewall?

Comment: By IP address. Or by subnet ofcourse. We have had cases where an external party gave us 1 hostname, but we had to implement it with multiple IP addresses.